# lualatex complains when using convert in standalone

Tags: luatex, standalone, shell-escape

With the following file I encounter an error when using both the `convert` option of `standalone` *and* `lualatex`. Switching either to `pdflatex` (which I cannot use for this drawing for other reasons) *or* converting by hand (which is inconvenient) does work.

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
%\documentclass{standalone}         % Does work but does not convert
\documentclass[convert]{standalone} % Does not work
\begin{document}
    MWE
\end{document}
```

How can I make `lualatex` work with the `convert` option?

I am using `lualatex --shell-escape filename` (or `pdflatex --shell-escape filename`) with an updates MikTeX.

---

**Additional info as requested:**

The error I get with `lualatex --shell-escape` is

```
\sa@box=\box37

! Bad number (18).
l.921     \ifeof18 
                 \else 3\fi
? 

Class standalone Warning: Shell escape disabled! Cannot convert file 'test.pdf'.
```

This is quite confusing to me as I explicitly used `--shell-escale` (and also `--enable-write18` with no difference).

Adding `\RequirePackage{shellesc}` didn't help (I tried adding it before and after `luatex85` as well as after `\documentclass`).

---

**Further Info**

The offending call stems form the file `standalone.cls` [2015/07/15 v1.2] within the following snippet starting at line 919:

```
\ifcase0%
    \expandafter\ifx\csname pdfshellescape\endcsname\relax
    \ifeof18 \else 3\fi
    \else\the\pdfshellescape\fi
\relax% 0
    \sa@convert@failuremsg
        {standalone}{Shell escape disabled! Cannot convert file '\infile'.}{}%
    \global\let\sa@convert@stop\relax
\or% 1
    \sa@convert{Conversion unsuccessful!\MessageBreak
                There might be something wrong with your\MessageBreak
                conversation software or the file permissions!}%
\else% 2 or 3
    \sa@convert{Conversion failed! Please ensure that shell escape\MessageBreak is enabled (e.g. use '-shell-escape').}%
\fi
```

Am I correct to assume that this tests for the availability of the `\write18` (shellescape) feature which gets called because something's wrong with `pdfshellescape`?

Comment: It might be a good idea if you cited the error you get.

Comment: If I should guess: add `\RequirePackage{shellesc}`.

Comment: This is a bug in standalone which has already been reported but so far without any working solution: https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/standalone/issues/23/no-write18-or-pdfxxx-commands-in-luatex

Comment: David, @ArTourter: The newest `standalone` version v1.3a 2018-03-26 fixes this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment by ArTourter pointed me towards the following solution (i.e. workaround).

The problem seems twofold:

1. The pdfTeX primitive `\pdfshellescape` is no longer defined in
   newer LuaTeX
2. The `\write18` feature is not implemented as
   `standalone` would expect.

**Problem 1** can be solved with the package `pdftexcmds` which defines `\pdf@shellescape` which more or less implements what `\pdfshellescape` is expected to do. Thus we can use

```
\RequirePackage{pdftexcmds}
\makeatletter
  \let\pdfshellescape\pdf@shellescape
\makeatother
```

to define a working `\pdfshellescape` macro.

**Problem 2** is already solved by the `shellesc` package which redefines `\write` to give access to the `\write18` feature as standalone expects.

Together the following successfully circumvents the bug in `standalone` and produces a pdf as well as a converted bitmap.

```
\RequirePackage{shellesc}                % implement \write18

\RequirePackage{pdftexcmds}              % fake \pdfshellescape so
\makeatletter                            % standalone knows about it
  \let\pdfshellescape\pdf@shellescape
\makeatother

\RequirePackage{luatex85}
%\documentclass{standalone}
\documentclass[convert]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  MWE
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Call with `lualatex --shell-escape`.